# てもらう and how it's used with particle に

Tags: grammar, particle-に, giving-and-receiving

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lp-2PNSANJ8) about てもらう and てくれる, and I don't really understand why てくれる always uses が, and てもらう always uses に to mark the person who does something for the speaker, especially about に and てもらう. For example, what's the difference between the following sentences?

> さくらがパーティーに誘ってもらった

> さくらにパーティーに誘ってもらった

why does てもらう always use に in the video? And not が？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

もらう ("to receive") is a verb that can take up to three particles (i.e., [trivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics))). A**が**B**に**C**を**もらう means "A (gratefully) receives C from B".

> 彼女**は**母**に**指輪**を**もらった。
> She received a ring from her mother.
> <sub>(が is replaced to は because it's the topic of the sentence)</sub>

が (or は) marks the subject who is the receiver, and に (or から) marks the giver. These rules won't change when もらう is used as a donatory subsidiary verb (i.e., when the given thing is a "favor" instead of a tangible object). Therefore:

> さくら**が**パーティーに誘ってもらった。
> Sakura was invited to a party (by someone, and she was grateful).
> <sub>(Read this as though Sakura received an imaginary invitation.)</sub>

> さくら**に**パーティーに誘ってもらった。
> [I/Someone] was invited to a party by Sakura (and I/he/she was grateful).

Of course you can use both が (は) and に and say something like this:

> 太郎が花子にパーティーに誘ってもらった。
> Taro was invited to a party by Hanako (and Taro was grateful).

Answer (score 0):

I remember when I first learned about してもらう、してあげる　and the like, it helped me to think translate it in my head as "to receive the action of ...~ing" or "to give the action of ...~ing" :

**さくらが**パーティーに誘ってもらった

**Sakura** *received the action of being invited* to the party.

i.e.; Sakura got invited to the party.

**さくらに**パーティーに誘ってもらった

[Someone] *received the action of being invited* to the party **by Sakura**.

i.e.; Sakura invited them to the party.